# Relevence tab for single word search

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, relevance

I see that if you do a search on stackoverflow.com for something like [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books), it forces it into a tag search, and the relevance tab isn't there (so the most important results are pretty much hidden)

But when you add a [second word](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=books+uml) you do get a relevance search and so, some very interesting posts come up.

So I guess what I'm asking is, where's da relevance tab for tag search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevance you are looking for is the Votes tab..

Comment: <p><span> sort ah </span></p>

Comment: I guess that is it!  But its just not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ermm.. my guess. A tag is a well... a tag! A tag search hit is a hit, everything tagged with that tag is considered equally relevent.

Well, please enlighten me if I'm wrong. :P